# Need help to create database schema for wholesale online tee store

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I'm currently working on wholesale online t-shirt shop. I have done this for fixed quantity and price, and its working fine. Now i need to do this for variable quantity and price.

I am trying to base my design on this [reference site](http://www.qtag.com/T-Shirts/Mens_Short_Sleeve_T-Shirts/Stedman_Mens_Budget_T-shirts?oscsid=c3c6127cde0b36a6a07ea1f154d12496).

Basic tables I have created are:

```
CREATE TABLE attribute (
  attribute_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (attribute_id)
); 

CREATE TABLE attribute_value (
  attribute_value_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  attribute_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  value varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (attribute_value_id),
  KEY idx_attribute_value_attribute_id (attribute_id)
);

CREATE TABLE  product (
  product_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  image varchar(150) default NULL,
  thumbnail varchar(150) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (product_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY idx_ft_product_name_description (name,description)
);

CREATE TABLE product_attribute (
  product_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  attribute_value_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (product_id,attribute_value_id)
);
```

I'm not getting, how to store the price based on a variable quantity. 
e.g -

```
Quantity    Price
1-9         £1.91
10-99       £1.64
100-499     £1.10
500+        £1.14
```

Please help me to create product and its related tables. My requirement is same as above reference link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a table that matches the pricing matrix shown on the site.

```
  CREATE TABLE product_qty_prices (
     id         INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     product_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES product,
     low_qty    INTEGER NOT NULL
     high_qty   INTEGER NOT NULL
     price      DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL )
```

You can also choose to omit the high_qty column and derive that in your application by looking at the low_qty from the next row, but I generally find it worth the risk of getting overlapping or incorrect ranges with this design.

Answer (score 2):

Get a copy of the Data Model Resource Book, volume 1 - 3 and look up well designed data schemata. Simply as needed (they are powerfull). Pricing in a store is not THAT simple - seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is a bit confused.  Do you want a generic Entity-Attribute-Value data model or a domain-specific model?  Modelling your specific domain directly is easier than trying to wrangle an abstract EAV implementation.

If you want to look at a sample implementation, Barry Williams's Library of Free Data Model has a good e-commerce example.  [Find out more](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/e_commerce/index.htm).